# Django: import data from CSV - tuple indices must be integers or slices, not str

Tags: python, django, pandas

In my Django APP I'd like to upload data to a model from a CSV.

For reading the data I'm using `pandas` library. But I'm getting this error:

> File
>   "D:\web_proyects\stickers-gallito-app\shop\management\commands\categories.py",
>   line 23, in 
>       for row in tmp_data_categories.iterrows() TypeError: tuple indices must be integers or slices, not str

I'm thinking is it because of how I've formulated my for loop, to read the data.

**models.py:**

```
class Category(models.Model):
    category = models.CharField(max_length=250, unique=True)
    slug = models.SlugField(max_length=250, unique=True)
    description = models.TextField(blank=True)
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to='category', blank=True, null=True)
    video = EmbedVideoField(null=True, blank=True)

    class Meta:
        ordering = ('category',)
        verbose_name = 'category'
        verbose_name_plural = 'categories'

    def get_url(self):
        return reverse('shop:allCat', args=[self.slug])

    def __str__(self):
        return '{}'.format(self.name)
```

**commands/categories.py:**

```
import pandas as pd
import csv
from shop.models import Category
from django.core.management.base import BaseCommand



tmp_data_categories=pd.read_csv('static/data/categories.csv',sep=',', encoding="utf-8")


class Command(BaseCommand):
    def handle(self, **options):
        categories = [
            Category(
                category=row['category'],
                slug=row['product'],
                subcategory=row['slug'],
                subcategory_slug=row['description'],
                description=row['size'],
                image =row['quantity'],
                video=row['image'],
        )
            for row in tmp_data_categories.iterrows()
        ]

        Category.objects.bulk_create(categories)
```

I'm getting the error when calling:

```
python manage.py categories
```

Answer (score 1):

Because iter over `iteritems` return a tupe which you can't index using strings. The second element of that tuple is pandas series which is subscriptable using string names. So you should be doning

```
categories = [
            Category(
                category=row['category'],
                slug=row['product'],
                subcategory=row['slug'],
                subcategory_slug=row['description'],
                description=row['size'],
                image =row['quantity'],
                video=row['image'],
        )
            for _, row in tmp_data_categories.iterrows()
        ]
```

Answer (score 1):

This doesn't work because django's [models.py](https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/db/models/query.py) is not a dict-like object.

But, why are you using pandas here, when you don't need to. Witness:

```
tmp_data_categories=csv.DictReader('static/data/categories.csv', fieldnames=['category', 'product', 'slug', 'description', 'size', 'quantity', 'image'])

categories = [
            Category(
                category=row['category'],
                slug=row['product'],
                subcategory=row['slug'],
                subcategory_slug=row['description'],
                description=row['size'],
                image =row['quantity'],
                video=row['image'],
        )
            for row in tmp_data_categories
        ]
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: got: `AttributeError: 'DictReader' object has no attribute 'iterrows'`

Comment: You know how to replace blanks from CSV to " " white space or null to be accepeted into DataBase, when using csv.DictReader?

Comment: I don't think that's possible to do readily. You can add another loop and do so yourself, though.